# Backbone.js fetch problem (can't refresh data immediately)

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I have such code:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend();

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/url/',
    model: MyModel
});
var coll = new MyCollection();
```

The url is correct and returns correct json. But if I try to use the next code:

```
$('#fetch').click(function(){
    coll.fetch();
    console.log(coll.toJSON());
});
```

- it shows me data only after the second click (http-response in firebug i see after the first one). It seems that data isn't refreshed in time.

If I put each statement in different event it works correct. But I need to know the length of collection immediately. How to do this?

Answer (score 24):

Keep in mind that `fetch` is an asynchronous call to the server. To make your code work as you expected, create a `success` function that `Backbone.Collection` can call once it refreshes its contents from the server:

```
$('#fetch').click(function(){
    coll.fetch({
        succcess: function() {
            console.log(coll.toJSON());
        }
    });    
});
```

Obviously you app doesn't need to really call `console.log` so a more real world example would use backbone's event binding like this:

```
coll.bind('refresh', someFunction);
coll.fetch();
```

With this approach, backbone will call `someFunction` when the collection refreshes. This is really useful especially when `someFunction` is the `render` function of a view to which you want to bind your collection.

```
coll.bind('refresh', yourView.render);
coll.fetch();
```

Comment: That event fires when the collection has finished receiving data from the server.

Comment: Not sure if this was a resent change but you now appear to need to bind to 'reset' instead of 'refresh'.

Answer (score 6):

From version 0.5.0 Collection.refresh was renamed to Collection.reset.

So in Andrew's answer (that I found very useful):

```
coll.bind('refresh', someFunction);
```

becomes

```
coll.bind('reset', someFunction);
```