# I can't get all attributes from a Backbone.js model

Tags: backbone.js

Here I am creating a new Divider with an ID, fetching the Divider, and displaying all attributes and a single attribute:

```
var divider = new Divider({id: "A"});
divider.fetch();
console.info(divider.attributes);
console.info(divider.get("title"));
```

The output of `console.info(divider.attributes)` shows attributes.title as an array with four strings; however; `console.info(divider.get("title"))` shows null. Can anyone think why it's coming back as null? The only attribute I can get is "id". Also, `console.info(divider.attributes.title)` also shows null.

Here is my Divider model:

```
Divider = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    "id": null,
    "title": null,
    "description": null
  }
}
```

Let me know if I can provider more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you figured out the async issue. I ran into the same issue as you, and figured out that when the data is being returned, your model's attributes are updated in the console. So at the time you are looking at your console, the fetch method has completed and your model has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

The Backbone.js fetch is asynchronous, so if you are depending on the attributes to be populated by fetch, you need to make sure to get the attributes after the fetch is complete. Here is an example:

```
var Divider = new Divider({id: "A"});
divider.fetch({success: function() {
  console.info(divider.get("title");
}});
```

However, I'm still not certain why `console.info(divider.attributes)` was showing attributes.title with the data, and `console.info(divider.attributes.title)` was showing as null.

Reference: [Backbone.js fetch problem (can't refresh data immediately)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048480/backbone-js-fetch-problem-cant-refresh-data-immediately)

Comment: I have run into the same issue before, and also for the life of me I could not figure it out. It looks as though the console is updated when the data is fetched. So at the time you are looking at your console, the data has already been fetched.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I believe that answers my question, so if you write it up, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewFerk missing a closing ) for console.info