# How to pass back model attribute from a view Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a controller:

```
            var layout = new LayoutView();
            App.holder1.show(layout);
            var my_view = new myView({id: options})
            layout.holder1.show();

            console.log(my_view.model.get('name')) <---- I want this
```

I want to `get my_view.model.get('name')` however, the issue is I get `undefined`. I have `console.log` the model and it is populated ok, however I think it's because it's not fully loaded yet when I try the get.

**This is my current thisView:**

```
  var thisView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            initialize: function (options) {
                this.model.fetch();
            },
            model: new myModel(),
            template: testExampleTemplate,
        });
        return thisView;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you need. You want to acces the id of the model outside, but you have a reference only to the view ?

Comment: I'll update the question to make more sense

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Backbone.js fetch problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6048480/722238). There's many more of these questions - with good answers kicking around stackoverflow.

Comment: @fbynite but the fetch success function happends inside that view. I need to somehow make somehow my_view.model.get('name') externally wait until the view has finished before assigning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for an event. "change" or "reset" will work.

```
viewInstance.model.on("change", function(){
    viewInstance.model.get("nameOfAttribute");
    // do something
});
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Comment: yes, but the problem I have with this is that the model.fetch() in the view has not finished loading so I get undefined.

Comment: ok, then listen for a change event on the model. There are other events you could listen for as well.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have the object populated only after the success callback function:

```
initialize: function (options) {
  this.model.fetch({
    success: function(model){
      console.log(model.get('name'));
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to approach this. First, you could listen for a change event from the model in the view, and do whatever it is you need when the change event fires. If you need to do something no matter what, you have a couple of options: you could write an implementation for you model's parse method that fires an event your view listens for and does something in response, or you can do something in the success callback for the fetch method itself (passed as an option to fetch). I can provide an example if I understand better which approach makes sense for your situation.